# convert polygon to extent

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I need to convert a polygon to an extent, so I can  put the converted value in the layer's "extent" option and request a relevant part of that layer. How do I do that? Tried searching for such method in the API, but found only the method that converts extent to polygon, but I need the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

Well,it turned out to be pretty simple. I just created new ol.geom.Polygon object, put coordinates in it's constructor and used getExtent() method on it.